# Setting bookmarks in SQL script saved to SSMS solution

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've just noticed that in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 19.1.56 I can't seem to be able to set a bookmark on a SQL script file open in a query window, if the script has been saved to the solution open in the SSMS Solution Explorer.  Is there a way to do this, or does some option need to be set to allow it?

I can set bookmarks in unsaved query windows.  I can also set bookmarks in SQL script files open in query windows as long as the scripts aren't included in the open solution.  It's only SQL scripts that are included in the open solution which I can't bookmark.